# How do i click on a link that loads a html page and then using ajax (without clicking anything) load an external html page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, loading

I have page1.html with a link to page2.html and when page2.html is loading i want to load inside it with AJAX the content of page3.html. Can someone provide me with a solution? I have tried this but it doesn't work. Thanks :)

This is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.search == "?istoselides") {
    $('#loading_content').load('what-we-do/istoselides.html').fadeIn(1000);
  }

  if (window.location.search == "?video") {
    $('#loading_content').load('what-we-do/etairika_video.html').fadeIn(1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: To OP or editor: My apologies if my edits collided with yours (I saw a brief "someone else edited this" message as I submitting the update).

Answer (score 0):

Does `window.location.search == "?istoselides"` return true, when page2 is loaded ?

Comment: how do i know if it turns true? (silly question... but yeah...) Thanks :)

Comment: just add alert before check :)